# HTML + IE6 + IE7 + IE8 + IE9, unclickable div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have `<div>Some text</div>`, and i want to make it **unclickable** (i want elements that under that div to be selected instead this div), **unselectable** (so user couldn't select text inside this div), **but visible**... **is it possible for  IE6 + IE7 + IE8 + IE9?**

**Update**

I just want to render some text on top of picture, but i want picture to be the only one who can catch mouse events.. so i want text to be rendered, but not involved in mouse events at all..

Comment: You want to prevent users from copying your content? Nope.

Comment: @Ai Is that DIV absolutely positioned?

Comment: Not sreal, i just want to render some text on top of picture, but want picture to be the only one who can catch mouse events.. so i want text to be rendered, but not involved in mouse events..

Comment: @sime-vidas well.. yes..

Comment: If you have the text as a child of the image div, absolutely positioned over the top, then the events will propagate up to the image div if you do not catch them.  The [text selection can be blocked via CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting).

Comment: Can you provide some example HTML/CSS which includes this picture?

Comment: @Richard You can find example at @Rodin answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable your text by setting the unselectable attribute `<p unselectable="on">` and setting the CSS property `-moz-user-select: none;`

Assuming your text is inside a `<p>` you can trigger a click to the image when p is clicked on.

```
$("p").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('img').trigger('click')
});

$('img').click(function() {
    alert('image clicked');
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/pavgY/1/

Comment: WOW :) it's really working everyware!! IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9.. tnx man... you saved my day..

Comment: +1 Very slick!  Also, if you want to make sure your HTML validates (pretty sure `unselectable` isn't in spec), you could add that for IE in JS.

Comment: Hmm.  I guess a lot can happen in a year.  That fiddle doesn't work for me in IE8 or in Chrome...

Answer (score 3):

Try overlaying the image and text with another div (named `capturebox` in my example) and capture mouse events on that.

In order for `capturebox` to really capture events in IE, it must have a background color set. To make it transparent, I give it an opacity of 0:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script>
            function captureclick(event) {
                alert('capurebox');
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .imgbox {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
            }

            .imgbox img {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }

            .imgbox p {
                cursor: default;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 50px;
            }

            .capturebox {
                filter: alpha(opacity=0);
                background-color: white;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="imgbox">
            <img src="yourimage.jpg"/>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <div class="capturebox" onclick="captureclick(event)"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool.. but this solution dosen't work in IE6... `filter: alpha(opacity=0);` isn't working in IE6

Comment: True. I wonder if it's possible at all in IE6. Take a look at this guide for inspiration: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: His example doesn't have a doctype, making it an awful example. http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: @reisio I would not say excluding a doctype makes it an 'awful' example.  Incomplete, yes, but awful?

Comment: @Rodin - I was looking at a similar solution.  I found that the user could still select the text by selecting the area surrounding the image, text and capturebox...  Not sure if there's a way around that.  Otherwise, I think this kind of technique is more elegant than using canvas and requiring a VML shim for IE.

Comment: @peteorpeter: yes, awful.  It's actually worse than no example at all.

Comment: @reisio: I'm terribly sorry for omitting the docstring. I was being lazy. The answer is now updated for optimal XHTML compliance. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @peteorpeter: I don't think being able to select the text is a problem in this case. It was not explicitly stated in the question that it should not be allowed, just that the default case would have to be to ignore mouse events on the text.

Comment: @Rodin: Yep, I was thinking "mouse events" would include selection, but OP updated to clarify that.
@reisio: Well, I admire your attention to detail!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteorpeter/Qs6tn/4/) (at least in Chrome and IE6, can't speak for IE7-9) using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to render the text on top, and a little jQuery to route events appropriately.

[image: gotta love marsupials!]

(Gotta love marsupials!)

I was surprised to find that the click event pass-through worked in VML in IE6!  Also, the VML is not selectable by default, which in this case is nice.

The starting markup is just `<img alt="the text you want to show" />`, so it's a pure JS enhancement.

This is basically the SVG-based equivalent of the canvas-based solution proposed by @Eldar.

Comment: It works perfectly for IE9, but that's all, click event dosen't work in IE7-IE8, in IE6 there is no text at all... http://cid-a1de71e9f2ae2f82.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/noname.png

Comment: Hmmm... My IE6 VM shows the text fine, and I did notice the IE7-8 click event trouble.  Oh well, I'm not going to dig any further - it was a heavy-handed solution to begin with!  @Hussein's approach is light years simpler.  At least I got to post a picture of a wombat.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var element = document.getElementById('content');
  element.onselectstart = function () { return false; } // ie
  element.onmousedown = function () { return false; } // mozilla
```

Try this

Comment: Text is not selecting, but this div still "capture" mouse events, so if i click on that div, element that under do not invoke onmousedown event..

Answer (score 1):

Could you just place a clear image on top?

Comment: nope.. text that i render on top of that image.. is varible.. so i nead an acsess to content of that div, but i what that div to be unclickable..

Answer (score 1):

You can use canvas to put text ontop of image. Sure HTML5 is not working for IE6 but you can use http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/ googles library to emulate it there.

Comment: this library use Silverlight... no sorry, i want to use pure Javascript, CSS, HTML..

Comment: too bad, I guess there are no good crossbrowser solution:( The text will anyway catch all events. You just have to deal with them.

Comment: The only problem is that Users that use IE6 will never install something like Silverlight or VML.. well.. at least the ones that i know :)